# codeigniter check box filtering

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i want to checkbox filtering in codeigniter... but it shows not correctly output...if anyone knows this please try to solve this

this is my controller

```
<?php  
class Check extends CI_Controller {
  public function laptops(){
    $this->load->model('check_m');
    $filter = array(
        'price' => $this->input->get('price'),
        'name' =>$this->input->get('name')
    );
    $data['laptop'] = $this->check_m->laptops_m($filter);

   // echo json_encode( $data['laptop'] );
   $this->load->view('check_view',$data);
 }
}
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class check_m extends CI_Model {
  function laptops_m($filter = null){
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('mobile_phones');
    // $query = $this->db->get('laptop_notebook')->result();
    // return $query;
    if($filter['name']){
      $this->db->where('name', $filter['name']);
    }
    if($filter['price']){
      $this->db->where('price', $filter['price']);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $query;
  }  
}
?>
```

View

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="acer" class="searcType">      
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="lenovo">    
<input type="checkbox" name="price" value="1000">   
<table>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($laptop as $laptops_all) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Laptop <?php echo $laptops_all->name ?> </p></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>  

<script>  
  $('.searchType').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));  //-->this will alert id of checked checkbox.
    if(this.checked){
      $.ajax({
        url: localhost/code/check/laptops,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            $("tbody").empty();
            $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+
              "Laptop "+element.brand+""+
              "</td></tr>");
            });
          }
      }); 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here i want to filter the items with checkboxes... but  i didn't get filtering output....

Comment: i want filtering check box in codeigniter..dynamically...what i want to do...is this correct code...or any modifications?

Comment: your question isn't clear. On checkbox click you want to filter data? right?
When matching string use like instead of where:
 $this->db->like('name', $filter['name']);

Comment: ya..already i tried in core php..that is ok...but in codeigniter it,s not working

Comment: i already submit my view code also

Comment: with like function also not working Mubeen Ahmed Sheikh

Comment: When using Ajax request in Codeigniter, try to send csrf_token with the request. It'll solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any parameters for **$this->input->get()** to pick up on.

If you are just sending a **GET** request, you won't need to send a **csrf_token** like someone mentioned in the comments.

---

You may need to check/set a few config variable's first.
These are in **application/config/config.php**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'; // OR AUTO
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

---

```
var BASEHREF = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
```

---

Your ajax options should then include the following

```
{
   url  : BASEHREF + 'check/laptops',
   type : 'GET',
   data : { name : 'toshiba', price : '1000'}
}
// GET http://yoursite.com/check/laptops?name=toshiba&price=1000
```